# No type or protocol named 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a ObjC & Swift Mixed project, it's use StoreKit to do IAP, the class's defines as follow:

```
...
import StoreKit
public class IAPManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver  {...}
...
```

when build it, it's failed with errors as follow:

[image: no type or protocol named'SKPaymentTransactionObserver']

[image: no type or protocol named'SKPaymentTransactionObserver']

the env is:

- xcode: v8.1
- iOS: 10.1
- swift: 2.3

I had googled for 1 hour, but can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the delegate method?.

**Swift 3**

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
}
```

Comment: it's say, 'there is no type or protocol',  not my class not confirm to the delegate